# Why mutt don't accept the password?

Tags: linux, mutt

I have a problem when I enter my gmail password, mutt shows me a notification **"login failed"** *my password is correct*

Comment: Hss this something to do with the TFA on Google accounts.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.